# Getting an invalid connection error while trying to make echo requests

Tags: go, network-programming, listener, ping, icmp

I am using go for creating a command-line app that tries pings a given host/IP address. I have used the following code in the main function and made the necessary imports/variable declarations outside.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/net/icmp"
    "golang.org/x/net/ipv4"
    "golang.org/x/net/ipv6"
)

var icmpType icmp.Type
var isIPv4 = false
var conn *icmp.PacketConn = nil
var start time.Time
var num int

var sequence int

func throwError(err error) {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}

func main() {

    host := "google.com"

    ttl := 64

    ipaddr, err := net.ResolveIPAddr("ip", host)

    if err != nil {
        throwError(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("The host is", host)
    fmt.Println("Address of processing is", ipaddr)

    if ipaddr.IP.To4() != nil {
        conn, err := icmp.ListenPacket("ip4:icmp", "0.0.0.0")
        if err != nil {
            throwError(err)
        }
        conn.IPv4PacketConn().SetTTL(ttl)
        isIPv4 = true
        icmpType = ipv4.ICMPTypeEcho
    } else {
        conn, err := icmp.ListenPacket("ip6:ipv6-icmp", "::")
        if err != nil {
            throwError(err)
        }
        conn.IPv6PacketConn().SetHopLimit(ttl)
        icmpType = ipv6.ICMPTypeEchoRequest
    }

    fmt.Println("isipv4", isIPv4)

    msg := icmp.Message{
        Type: icmpType, Code: 0,
        Body: &icmp.Echo{
            ID: os.Getpid() & 0xffff, Seq: 0,
            Data: []byte(""),
        },
    }

    msgBytes, err := msg.Marshal(nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    _, err = conn.WriteTo(msgBytes, ipaddr)
    if err != nil {
        // error occurs inside this block
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

}
```

Specifically, as far as I was able to figure out, the error occurs after I call the `conn.WriteTo` function.

The error message is `invalid connection`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest to start by writing the code as idiomatic Go. There are two places to focus attention: 1. no "throwError", return instead and 2. if msg.Marshal returns an error, the code keeps going, while it should return. It would be also nice to provide code that can be copied and pasted and run, instead of an excerpt.

Comment: I have updated the post with the complete code. The code stops even though I don't call the throwError function

Comment: You added the missing code, while I also asked to perform some changes. If you want my help, do your part :-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps replace all your

```
throwError(err)
```

with

```
fmt.Errorf("Error information: %s", err.Error())
```

for more information on exactly where/why the err is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The invalid connection might be due to the fact that you run your program unprivileged. Using 'ip4:icmp' and net.IPAddr only works if you run your programm in priviledged mode, e.g. using sudo. 
If you want to use ListenPacket unprivileged, you cannot use 'ip4:icmp' as network but 'upd4', c.f. https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/icmp#ListenPacket.
In case your are using 'udp4' as network in ListenPacket your WriteTo has to use net.UDPAddr instead of net.IPAddr.

Like this:
https://play.golang.org/p/qnxOYbVgk26

Comment: I actually ran my program using `sudo` but the error still persists

Comment: Strange, i tried both version using the code snippet i posted in the play (ip4:icmp and upd4) and both worked for me.